# Global toggle for MediaWiki collapsible elements

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am using the [mw-collapsible](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Collapsible_elements) class in Timeless skin to present some content as collapsed by default. However, I would like to a) either retain the state (collapsed or expanded) in all other pages where it is used once one clicks on it or b) provide some other form of global toggle as for example with the Show/Hide translations in [wiktionary Visibility sidebar menu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comparison#Translations). For b) I have tried adding the [Gadgets](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Gadgets) [Gadget-VisibilityToggles.js](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-VisibilityToggles.js) (where the code to add the "Visibility" sidebar heading exists) and [Gadget-defaultVisibilityToggles.js](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-defaultVisibilityToggles.js) but I could not get the toggles to be displayed on the sidebar.

This is the code used in the template

(`{{{trtx}}}` stands for the collapsible content):

```
==Translations==
<span class="mw-customtoggle-1" style="font-size:12px; line-height:1.6; display:inline-block; float:right; margin: 6px;"><span class="mw-customtoggletext" style="border-radius: 10px; background:#5f5f62; color: #ffffff; padding: 6px">Show/Hide</span><br/>
<div id="mw-customcollapsible-1" class="mw-collapsible mw-collapsed"></span>
{{{trtx}}}
</div>
```

And a couple of example pages where the template is used, [fragment](https://lsj.gr/wiki/fragmentum#Translations), [θυσία](https://lsj.gr/wiki/%CE%B8%CF%85%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1#Translations)